# use catch throwable or catch Exception in new thread of execution

Tags: java, try-catch

I need to find out best-practice for try-catch when launching a new thread.

Personally, I prefer Option 2.

Which option is the best-practice? Are there any factors that might make either option a best practice in some situations and not others?

Option 1

```
public void run(){
  try{
     //do something
   }catch(Exception e){
     // log 
   }
}
```

Option 2

```
public void run(){
  try{
     //do something
   }catch(Throwable t){
     // log
    }
}
```

EDIT: Assume that you are writing the code that has to meet a stringent code review.
EDIT 2: I know the difference between the above two options. I am just curious about what is seen as '100% correct' by others.

Comment: What do you mean by 'launching a new thread'?

Comment: @JVerstry new Thread( myRunnableObj ).start();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(...) on the thread to catch what the runnable does not handle properly, but when it comes to the runnable itself, it really depends on what it has to achieve and to reasonably anticipate considering a reasonable execution context.

On the other side, creating a separate thread to execute a runnable is not a good strategy IMHO, [FutureTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) deals with these issues better.

Comment: I may be wrong be wrong, but the method signature of UncaughtExceptionHandler [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html)  seems to indicate that it equates 'catching throwable'

Comment: Yes, but you don't have to put it in ALL runnables. What if you forget to put try/catch it in a runnable? This handler means less duplicate code.

Comment: So, would u say that you prefer Option 2 (with the condition that the catch-throwable is implemented using UnCaughtExceptionHandler) ?

Comment: @rk2010 Yes, I like to know about what I did not anticipate properly in my code. When there are totally unexpected situations, it is always good to collect information in order to debug/analyze them (especially if the application crashed). This handler is not expensive to implement and is a good safety net. In critical cases, whatever info it logs has the same value as a black box when a plane crashes.

Comment: To make it clear, I would still have my runnable handle reasonably expectable exceptions in its own code, but for the unexpected, I would leave it to the handler.

Answer (score 4):

In a root exception handler that simply logs whatever went wrong, distinguishing between `Error` and `Exception` is pointless, so catching `Throwable` is perfectly acceptable.

If instead you were writing some retry logic, I'd catch `Exception`, since there really is no point retrying after an `Error` - in fact, it could be dangerous, because the error was thrown in code that was not exception safe, and thus might have left the system in an inconsistent state.

Therefore, it depends on what kind of exception handler you are writing.

Comment: you said "catching Throwable is acceptable", so would u also say that "catching Exception is acceptable"?

Comment: For the logging exception handler? No. You don't want to distinguish between Errors and Exceptions, so why write two catch blocks, needlessly duplicating code? Or even worse, log one exception with a catch block, and the other with the Thread's UncaughtExceptionHandler? Keep it simple!

Comment: sorry for the confusion,  my earlier Question should have been : would either Option1 and Option2 be 'acceptable' to you?

Comment: No. Catching only exceptions will cause Errors not to be logged (or logged to the wrong place by the UncaughtExceptionHandler). Why would anyone want that?

Comment: gotcha. I prefer Option 2 also.

Answer (score 1):

It is never advisable to catch `Throwable` since this includes errors that cannot be handled or avoided such as out of memory error and so on.  Thus it is generally much better to catch `Exception` and not catch `Throwable`.  Sometimes it is unavoidable such as when calling invoke method or other reflection methods.

Comment: yeah, but at least throwable can caught and logged..  In Option 1 If a java.lang.Error does occur, the thread won't even log anything, and just disappear without a trace

Comment: I don't want the run to throw any kind of exception. Because the worflow that launches these threads, doesn't care what happens to them after they are started.  My interest is only in making life easier when things go bad. I don't want to get in a situation when java.lang.Error does occur, and it doesn't get logged.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to ask about is the concept of a fault barrier and the correct way to implement one should be a standard defined by the project you are working on or the framework you are using.

If your project has a policy to log all exceptions/errors and not let anything print to standard error, you might want to look into using an [UncaughtExceptionHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html).

A general best practice would be to catch only instances of RuntimeException.

```
public void run(){
  try{
     //do something
   }catch(RuntimeException e){
     // log 
   }
}
```

Catching `Exception` is too general because the Java language requires programs to deal with checked exceptions. By catching even checked exceptions at your fault barrier you are allowing the code in the `//do something` block to be sloppy and not handle checked exceptions.

Catching `Error` or `Throwable` is also generally considered a bad practice since an Error typically indicates that the JVM is in a state where it can not continue to function meaningfully.

Here is a good (and somewhat relevant) article on exception handling: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/entarch/effective-exceptions-092345.html

Comment: @TimBender  thanks for the link.  The 'bad state' will probably go away after thread dies. why should we not catch and log the bad state?

Comment: Because "probably" is not "certain", and the bad state might cause weird bugs.

Comment: @meriton  Oh come on.. I thought u had just now agreed that Option 2 is the preferred way acc. to you?

Comment: @TimBender  I like this idea.. but isn't using [UnCaughtExceptionHandler](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) the same as `catch(Throwable)` ?

Comment: @rk2010,  my personal opinion is that catching `Exception` or `Throwable` is wrong (with few exceptions) since it strips away some compile time safety regarding checked exceptions. If it is desired to catch `Error` for logging, I think that is fine. However, my preference would be to include a separate catch block and not generalize to `Throwable`. I realize that this means possibly adding a catch block for every checked exception the code won't handle, but at least the intent in handling each is clear. The "right thing" to do is truly subject depending on project/framework policies.

Comment: @rk2010: That comment was directed at trying to recover from an Error, which is generally impossible. (c.f. the second paragraph of my answer). Logging - and then terminating the process - is fine. Trying to continue after a java.lang.OutOfMemoryError is asking for trouble.

Comment: @rk2010, `but isn't using UnaughtExceptionHandler the same as catch(Throwable)`. NO! Absolutely not, the difference is subtle but important. `catch(Throwable)` tells the compiler "I don't care what happens, if anything goes wrong just jump to here". Which means you (or someone else) could add some code that uses an API which throws a meaningful **checked exception** and not handle it properly. Using an `UncaughtExceptionHandler` means only **unchecked exceptions** and Errors (which are unchecked) will be handled.

Comment: @TimBender  I agree with that point about checked exceptions. With a `catch(Throwable)` developers may be get lazy and never write `catch` blocks for checked Exceptions.  _However_ my main concern is:  do you prefer to handle Throwable  (by using either `catch(Throwable)` or that `UnCaughtExceptionHandler`), or do you prefer let it go unhandled ?

Comment: @rk2010, Since you are just logging I would probably use an UncaughtExceptionHandler as the action being performed isn't business logic a try/catch block would just add clutter. Using an UncaughtExceptionHandler also lends itself to reducing duplicate code. I had previously upvoted JVerstry's answer.